# Fiz a implementação do fb:app_id mas no debug não está sendo identificado

Tags: html5, css3

fiz a implementação do:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="966242223397117" />
```

Mas quando faço o debug pelo endereço: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/
 ele informa que não foi declarado.